# different attributes for the same tag in CSS

Tags: css

To make all my H1 headings be centered, I enter the following in a CSS sheet:

h1 {text-align:center;}

Can someone advise how to define a different alignment for H1 tags in the same CSS sheet? i.e. I want some H1 to be centered and some to be left aligned.

Thanks!

Comment: This is what [css classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) are for.

Comment: Your looking to use CSS class selectors or id's to apply formatting to specific elements. Check the [Class Selector docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors)

Comment: Thanks, those links are useful! it's been 20 years since I looked at HTML coding, now I am streaming HTML responses to a server using dBase, so I need to learn the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using classes.
You can add something like

```
<h1 class="center">Centered</h1>
<h1 class="left">Left Aligned</h1>
```

Then your CSS

```
h1.center {
  text-align: center;
}
h1.left {
  text-align: left;
}
```

More info here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors

Answer (score -1):

Use classes for distinguishment. Since `text-align: inline-start` is the default, which translates to `left` since we read from *left* to right, you need to only add one class for `text-align: center`.

```
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

And then via HTML:

```
<h1>I'm Left</h1>
<h1 class="center">I'm centered</h1>
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the most used alignment as default and apply class to do other alignment options. like the snippet:

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;

}

h1.left {
  text-align: left;

}
```